# ¿Como inicializar correctamente un struct sin referencias?

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy atascado en una de mis tareas, es la siguiente :

> Implementa el método popularity_init (..) que dados un film y una
>   estadística para este, retorne un elemento de tipo tPopularity
>   rellenando sus campos. No debe referenciarse al film existente,
>   debemos hacer una copia del film.

La estructura de la función es la siguiente:

```
tError popularity_init(tPopularity* object, tFilmStats fs, tFilm film);
```

Lo que he implementado yo es lo siguiente:

```
tError popularity_init(tPopularity* object, tFilmStats fs, tFilm film) {
    // PR3_EX1 

    object =(tPopularity *)malloc(sizeof(tPopularity));

    tFilm *fill =  (tFilm*)malloc(sizeof(tFilm));

    film_cpy(fill,&film);
    film_cpy(&object->film,fill); 

    object->stats.numUserFavorited = fs.numUserFavorited;
    object->stats.numUserViews =fs.numUserViews;

}
```

Añado la definicion de las estructuras:

```
typedef struct {
    tFilm film;
    tFilmStats stats;
} tPopularity;

typedef struct {
    unsigned int numUserViews;
    unsigned int numUserFavorited;
} tFilmStats;

typedef struct { 
    char* title;    
    unsigned short lengthInMin;
    tSeries *series;
} tFilm;

typedef struct {
    char* title;
    int genre;    
} tSeries;
```

En cuanto a `film_cpy` (`film_cpy(tFilm* dst, tFilm* src)`), no es necesario el código, ya que es un método ya testeado y funcial que copia una pelicula en otra.
Sin embargo no pasa los tests que evaluan el programa, pero no veo por qué , ya que los datos sí se copian.

¿Es correcto como estoy haciendo la inicialización o hay algún fallo de memoria?
El test que mi código no pasa es el siguiente...¿por qué?

```
tPopularityList popularityList;

// TEST 8: Create popularity element
    failed = false;
    start_test(test_section, "PR3_EX1_2B", "Create popularity element");

    fs.numUserFavorited = 123;
    fs.numUserViews = 321;

    if (OK != popularity_init(&pop, fs, film[6])) {
        failed = true;
    }

    if (!failed)
    {
        if (0 != strcmp(pop.film.title, "Film6")) {
            failed = true;
        }

        if (pop.film.lengthInMin != 106) {
            failed = true;
        }

        if (pop.film.series != &series) {
            failed = true;
        }

        if (pop.stats.numUserViews != 321 || pop.stats.numUserFavorited != 123) {
            failed = true;
        }
    }

    popularity_free(&pop);

    if (failed) {
        end_test(test_section, "PR3_EX1_2B", false);
        passed = false;
    }
    else {
        end_test(test_section, "PR3_EX1_2B", true);
    }
```

Un saludo!

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta

Comment: Según la declaración parece que tu función de inicialización debería retornar algo de tipo `tError`, y no veo que retorne nada. El test parece esperar que retornes la constante `OK`.

Comment: Vaya error de novato... efectivamente, ese debe ser un error, sin embargo, ahora retorno un OK, pero el programa no se ejecuta(se lanza pero se aborta al instante), es decir, tiene algún fallo de memoria en mi código. Al estar programando con CodeLite en windows no puedo debuggear y ver donde se genera, es realmente horrible